# MacBook Air screen keeps turning off after fall

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a 2022 MacBook Air M2. I dropped it on its side while the lid was open. The top left corner of the screen cracked slightly. And for a few days, the laptop and screen still worked, just with the small crack. But then, after a few days the screen starts turning off when I open the lid.

1. If the screen has been working while the lid is open, it continues working, no issues.
2. When I close the lid and re-open it, the screen comes on, stays on for 5 seconds and then turns back off. The laptop is still working since I can use it with an external display just fine.
3. If I keep opening and closing the lid, the screen eventually comes back on and stays on.
4. If I connect the laptop to a charger and then open and close the lid, it still turns off after 5 seconds but tends to get to a stable state where it stays on sooner.

Because of #1, I feel this isn't an issue with the screen itself. Looking up online, I found someone who said the display port was loose when they had dropped their Mac [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+screen+goes+blank+due+to+cracked+display&newwindow=1&client=safari&sca_esv=561127711&rls=en&sxsrf=AB5stBj793VI1trPTsMAw5RDucb9B7HsZQ%3A1693356972448&ei=rJPuZPb8GpDk0PEPncu8YA&ved=0ahUKEwj2gsimloOBAxUQMjQIHZ0lDwwQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=mac+screen+goes+blank+due+to+cracked+display&gs_lp=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&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:fc39cee8,vid:9aNI7NaOuTE). But the steps they follow seem very involved. I'm wondering if someone can look at the symptoms above and tell me what the likely cause is?

Comment: Take it to get it checked by a professional.

Comment: The cause is physical damage. Do you have household insurance that might cover this?

Comment: Nope, no insurance. But why do you say household insurance? You mean Apple care or something right?

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem began after physical damage, the only conclusion we can pull here is that something got dislodged inside the machine. If you are unwilling to take the machine apart yourself, the only thing that can be recommended is taking it to a certified service point to be diagnosed. This is not going to be something you fix with an easy trick.